# An error occurred while creating datasets: Dataset could not be created (Apache-Superset 2.0.0)

Tags: dataset, dashboard, apache-superset

I am using apache-superset version 2.0.0.
While trying to create a dataset , I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while creating datasets: Dataset could not be created. (error 422)
```

On the other hand, I am able to run a query on the same table, but without a dataset, I cannot use create charts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please could you add some more info, what dataset you want create? can you run query in SQL lab? Some more info would be helpful

Comment: I can run a query in SQL lab after that I can't create a virtual dataset using the query on the other hand I can't make a physical dataset as well.